# How to get variables within class without self reference

Tags: python, class

I have a class:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
  
    param_outside_function = param #<-------------- how to get the variable param inside the class and outside the class function without using `self`?
```

Comment: It's not really clear why you need this. If `param` is an instance variable, it could be different for each instance of `B` and so the value outside the instance is ambiguous. If it is not different for each instance, then it probably shouldn't be an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

use `global param` instead of "self" and declare it outside the class

Comment: still cannot print variable

    `global param_outside_function 

class B(A):
        def __init__(self, param):
            param_outside_function  = param
  
        print(param_outside_function )`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to understand what you need, but maybe this can help :
Create a method that return this variable, but you will still be using self.method :

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
  
    def getParam(self):
        return self.param
```